# Finite difference central scheme equivalent for non centered point

Tags: finite-differences

I need to use a central difference scheme:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y_{i+1}-y_{i-1}}{2 \Delta x}$$

equivalent for non centered point:

[image]

Unfortunately I cannot find a book in which I have this formula. Could anybody give me this in answer?

Comment: This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2006681/418542) is related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you can use Taylor expansion to derive the formula
$$y_{i-1}=y(x-\Delta x_i)=y(x)-\frac{dy}{dx}\Delta x_i+O(\Delta x^2)$$
$$y_{i+1}=y(x+\Delta x_{i+1})=y(x)+\frac{dy}{dx}\Delta x_{i+1}+O(\Delta x^2)$$
By neglecting higher order terms $O(\Delta x^2)$
$$y_{i+1}-y_{i-1}=\frac{dy}{dx}\Delta x_{i+1}+\frac{dy}{dx}\Delta x_i\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y_{i+1}-y_{i-1}}{\Delta x_{i+1}+\Delta x_i}$$

Comment: Have forgotten that. :] Thanks!